# $A_i \subset B_i$ and $\bigcap A_i$ finite while $\bigcap B_i$ infinite, then $\bigcap B_i \setminus A_i$ is also infinite.

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-writing

**Proposition.** If $|\bigcap_{i \in I} A_i | \lt \infty, \ B_i \supset A_i, \ \forall i \in I, \ $ and $|\bigcap_{i \in I} B_i| = \infty$, then $|\bigcap_{i \in I} (B_i \setminus A_i)| = \infty$.

**Proof.** ?

Attempt: $X = \bigcap_{i} B_i \setminus A_i = \bigcap_i B_i \cap A_i^c$, but this equals $(\bigcap_i B_i) \cap (\bigcap_i A_i^c)$, by rearranging $\cap$'s.    If $X$ were finite, then ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The result is false as stated: if $I=\Bbb N$, $B_n=\Bbb N$ for each $n\in\Bbb N$, and $A_n=\{n\}$ for each $n\in\Bbb N$, then $\bigcap_{n\in\Bbb N}B_n=\Bbb N$, which is infinite, and $\bigcap_{n\in\Bbb N}A_n=\varnothing$, which is finite, but

$$\bigcap_{n\in\Bbb N}(B_n\setminus A_n)=\bigcap_{n\in\Bbb N}(\Bbb N\setminus\{n\})=\varnothing$$

is finite.

Comment: What if $A_n$ is an infinite set?

Comment: @StudySmarterNotHarder: Let $\{C_n:n\in\Bbb N\}$ be a family of pairwise disjoint infinite sets disjoint from $\Bbb N$. Let $A_n=\{n\}\cup C_n$ and $B_n=\Bbb N\cup C_n$. The intersections are the same as before, but the sets $A_n$ are now all infinite.